# RxJs combineLatest seem to simulate an additional update

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

While I know what's mentioned in the subject sounds ridiculous, it feels more so once you look at the code. However, I have spent several hours trying to go through API and play around with my code with no logical explanation to why it's not working as per expectations.

My code intends to have x and y buttons, which on being clicked will increment their own text content with specific amount, which is 3 for x and 1 for y. Initial values of x and y is initialised to 2 and 5 respectively. I have used combineLatest with an aim to have text content of sum button to get updated with new values of x and y.

While it seem to work alright for the most part, on the first click of x or y, the text content shows the right number but the sum seem to have received the next value (future value?) which I expect it to have received on the subsequent click. It's getting hard for me to explain it in words, but I am sure if you try click any of the buttons twice, you will spot the issue. Thanks for reading this far, please help me out.

```js
const makeButtonTextUpdater = buttonElt => value => buttonElt.textContent = value;

const xElt = document.getElementById('x');
const yElt = document.getElementById('y');
const sumElt = document.getElementById('sum');
const xClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(xElt, 'click');
const yClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(yElt, 'click');
const sumClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(sumElt, 'click');

const xValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  s.next(2); // default value
  xClick$.subscribe(e => {
    s.next(parseInt(e.target.textContent) + 3)
  });
});
const yValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  s.next(5); // default value
  yClick$.subscribe(e => {
    s.next(parseInt(e.target.textContent) + 1)
  });
});
const sumValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  rxjs.combineLatest(xValue$, yValue$).subscribe(([x, y]) => {
    s.next(parseInt(x) + parseInt(y));
  });
});

xValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt));
yValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(yElt));
sumValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(sumElt));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<label>x: <button id="x">0</button></label>
<label>y: <button id="y">0</button></label>
<label>sum: <button id="sum">0</button></label>
```

PS: I know there are better ways to get the job done with pipes, but since I am new I would like to explore things at my own pace. While I am open to alternate solutions, I would very much like to know why my code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your code did't work:

*Uh, thats tough...* You definitely have double subscriptions in the buttons, meaning that code inside `new Observable` for buttons would be run twice (first when `nValue$` is subscribed to and then when `combineLatest` is). Run twice means that it has two handlers for each btn onClick.

So, when you click on x or y -- you `.next` to two Observable chains: one that updates btn text and the other for the summ value update.

First your chain for button text update executes and updates btn value.

Then chain for summ text update is activated. And when it is summing values -- it reads already updated values from the btn text. Because of the previous chain execute.

Try modifying your on click subscriptions code to do logging. E.g.

```js
yClick$.subscribe(e => {
        const value = parseInt(e.target.textContent)
        console.log('y click', value);
        s.next(value + 1);
      });
```

You'll see that it's run twice. First it reads value at t1 and updates it. Then it is executed second time and now reads next value from btn text.

This seems to be the case.

**Important note:** this approach with Observable constructors and inner subscriptions should be primarily used for education. It is error prone and usually excessive, as most of the tasks are solved using existing operators or by combining them. If you're using the constructor -- most likely you're doing it wrong.

There are a lot of constructor alternatives for Observable creation:

- [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)
- [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEventPattern)
- [defer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/defer.html) [example](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/defer/)
- [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif.html)
- ...

So here's an updated example using pipes:

```js
const makeButtonTextUpdater = buttonElt => value => buttonElt.textContent = value;
const xElt = document.getElementById('x');
const yElt = document.getElementById('y');
const sumElt = document.getElementById('sum');
const xClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(xElt, 'click');
const yClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(yElt, 'click');
const sumClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(sumElt, 'click');

const xSumm$ = xClick$.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.startWith(2),
  rxjs.operators.scan((acc)=>(acc + 3))
)

const ySumm$ = yClick$.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.startWith(5),
  rxjs.operators.scan((acc)=>(acc + 1))
);

xSumm$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt));
ySumm$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(yElt));

rxjs
  .combineLatest(xSumm$, ySumm$, (x, y)=>x+y)
  .subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(sumElt));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<label>x: <button id="x">0</button></label>
<label>y: <button id="y">0</button></label>
<label>sum: <button id="sum">0</button></label>
```

Comment: I was able to follow your description until "...button text update executes and updated btn value". However, it is still not clear how combineLatest gets the next value which is not spit out by xValue$ yet. I have also put several console logs to confirm that xValue$ does not spit out any new value until it is clicked. Please help me understand this, highly appreciate your efforts.

I believe it's important for me to understand the bug to be able to learn RxJs. Thanks for the alternate approach though, that will help me write concise code in future.

Comment: @Jack sorry, a typo, should've been "updates". I've updated the explanation a bit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, got it now. Though I must mention that explanation from @DhananjayaKuppu also helped a lot. In a nut shell my since my xValue$ is subscribed twice, the xClick$ is also run twice, which causes the value to increment twice. The most precise fix for this would be to move the increment logic outside of xValue$ and use it just to push new values.

```
xClick$.subscribe(e => {
  e.target.textContent = parseInt(e.target.textContent) + 3;
});
xValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  s.next(2);
  xClick$.subscribe(e => {
    s.next(parseInt(e.target.textContent))
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the below approach:

```js
const makeButtonTextUpdater = buttonElt => value => buttonElt.textContent = value;

const xElt = document.getElementById('x');
const yElt = document.getElementById('y');
const sumElt = document.getElementById('sum');
const xClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(xElt, 'click');
const yClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(yElt, 'click');
const sumClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(sumElt, 'click');

const xValue$ = xClick$.pipe(
                  rxjs.operators.pluck('target', 'textContent'),
                  rxjs.operators.map(v => parseInt(v) + 3),
                  rxjs.operators.startWith(2),
                  rxjs.operators.tap(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt))
                  );

   const yValue$ = yClick$.pipe(
                  rxjs.operators.pluck('target', 'textContent'),
                  rxjs.operators.map(v => parseInt(v) + 1),
                  rxjs.operators.startWith(5),
                  rxjs.operators.tap(makeButtonTextUpdater(yElt))
               );

   const sumValue$ = rxjs.combineLatest(xValue$, yValue$)
                     .pipe(
                          rxjs.operators.tap(console.log),
                          rxjs.operators.map(v => v[0]+v[1])
                      );

  
//xValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt));
//yValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(yElt));
sumValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(sumElt));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<label>x: <button id="x">0</button></label>
<label>y: <button id="y">0</button></label>
<label>sum: <button id="sum">0</button></label>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it will surely help me write better code in future. However, I am not able to let go of the bug I am facing without understanding the cause. Please help me understand. Appreciate time and efforts that you put into this.

Comment: I have added explanation in new answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is xClick$ is getting subscribed twice:

1. xValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt));
2. rxjs.combineLatest internal subscription;

When x button clicked (x = 2) xClick$ subscription executes as:

1. xValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt)); // emits (2+3) and updates DOM
2. rxjs.combineLatest internal subscription takes latest value from DOM (5+3) = 8 and combineLatest subscription takes x=8, y=5

```js
const makeButtonTextUpdater = buttonElt => value => buttonElt.textContent = value;

const xElt = document.getElementById('x');
const yElt = document.getElementById('y');
const sumElt = document.getElementById('sum');
const xClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(xElt, 'click');
const yClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(yElt, 'click');
const sumClick$ = rxjs.fromEvent(sumElt, 'click');

const xValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  s.next(2); // default value
  xClick$.subscribe(e => {
    console.log('xClick=', e.target.textContent )
    s.next(parseInt(e.target.textContent)+3)
  });
});
const yValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  s.next(5); // default value
  yClick$.subscribe(e => {
            console.log('xClick=', e.target.textContent )

    s.next(parseInt(e.target.textContent) + 1)
  });
});


const sumValue$ = new rxjs.Observable(s => {
  rxjs.combineLatest(xValue$, yValue$).subscribe(([x, y]) => {
    console.log(x, y)
    s.next(parseInt(x) + parseInt(y));
  });
});

xValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(xElt));
yValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(yElt));

sumValue$.subscribe(makeButtonTextUpdater(sumElt));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<label>x: <button id="x">0</button></label>
<label>y: <button id="y">0</button></label>
<label>sum: <button id="sum">0</button></label>
```